# Inserting text values from list to a table, created in SQLite database

Tags: python, list, sqlite, syntax-error

I am creating a database to store all the values from the lists defined in my code. 
I need the column - Input_CAN_signals to have each element of the list(input_can_signals) as its value. 
The output should look something like this:

Input_CAN_signals

signal -1

signal -2

signal --3

and so on.

So I have written the following code:

```
sql_obj = sqlite3.connect(sql_db_path)
c = sql_obj.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Signals1(Input_CAN_Signals, Output_CAN_signals, Input_LIN_Signals, Input_Hardware_Pin, Output_Hardware_Pin)")
i = 0     
for i in range(0,len(input_can_signals)):
        sig = 'INSERT INTO Signals1 (Input_CAN_Signals) VALUES(%s)'
        c.executemany(sig, input_can_signals[i])
```

Now, this gives the following error:

```
near "%" : syntax error
```

Comment: Sqlite uses `?` (or names starting with a few different characters) for parameters.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam